# Looking for a minimal triple with /ɑ, ɒ, ɔ/

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonemes, rhoticity

I am looking for a minimal triple for a particular set of phonemes.  By minimal triple, I mean three actual English words that differ in one and only one phoneme between them.  Examples therefore include:

- *phony, tony, pony*
- *swim, swam, swum*
- *bad, bat, bath*

The three phonemes that must appear one apiece in each of the three words are: `/ɑ, ɒ, ɔ/`.  I can get pairs, but no triples, and I wonder why.

Length doesn’t count, so for example `/aː/` counts as `/a/` and `/ɔː/` counts as `/ɔ/`.

If such a triple exists, what is it?

If no such triple exists, ***could*** it?  Or do the various mergers preclude a threefold phonemic distinction here?

These have all to be in the same accent, of course.  And preferably a rhotic one, too, because I’m trying to figure out something in particular about phonemic perception in rhotic speakers of North America, and non-rhotic accents will not further that goal.

As a last resort, if the only such triple you can find is a non-rhotic one, then go ahead and offer that one, perhaps along with some suggested explanation why there “can’t” be an equivalent rhotic triple.

Comment: For clarity: /ɑ, ɒ, ɔ/ is approximately the PALM, CLOTH, THOUGHT vowels of RP?

Comment: @MarkBeadles Yes, I think so, but I don’t myself have an /ɑ/ in any of them, so I may be a poor example. /ɑ/ is like a Latin/Romance *a*, with no rounding at all. I round all those three lexical sets. [This is the best site I know](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/) for regional English accents from all over Britain and beyond, along with sound clips and IPA.

Comment: baa-ed (like a sheep), bod (sweet one on that chick), bawd? OR ahs (oohs and...), Oz, awes

Comment: alms, oms, ohms?

Comment: pom, Pom, palm, poem?

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, it wouldn't surprise me if  baa-ed, bawd, bod might work somewhere too.

Comment: *baa'd* could be the real words *bard* or *barred* where I come from. There's no /r/.

Comment: Woah! Some people pronounce "bath" with a short "a" instead of a longer "ah" sound‽ That kinda blows my mind for some reason.

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir: It's common in the north of England.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For RP, doesn't *khan, con, corn* work?

If you allow widely-known foreign foods, how about *pawed, pod, pad,* where *pad* is as in *pad thai* (and that one even works for rhotic accents).

Comment: I think you win.  *Pawed, pod, pad* are very attractive. It takes a lot of conscious effort to generate three different phonemes there, for me personally. I keep wanting to merge either *pawed* with *pod*  ***or else*** *pod* with *pad*, although never all three the way the LA (well, SoCal/LoCal) accent does. The difference between *pawed* and *pod* is pretty subtle for me; I must be keying on roundedness without caring how much. That’s the thing I was trying to track down. Are they all 3 distinct for you?  You’re a Massachusetts native, or import? Boston, or elsewhere?

Comment: I'm an import, and I pronounce *pad* and *pod* the same, but *pawed* is distinct. With a Boston accent (I just realized), *pod* and *pawed* are pronounced the same but *pad* is distinct. I may have been living here long enough that I think of all three as distinct. So maybe I don't win.

Comment: My hypothesis is that there is no North American accent with more than two out of three distinct words in *pawed / pod / pad*.  I have two, and you have two, and people with the *cot–caught* merger have only one.  You win because you have picked a good triple to test this hypothesis with. That’s just what I was looking for, even if it isn’t a threefold distinction for me personally.

Comment: This answer helped me better understand the O.P.'s question. I pronounce "pawed" and "pod" as homophones; I'd pronounce "I pawed my iPod" the same as "iPod my I pawed" (though only the former would be sensical).

Comment: I've always heard the "pad" as in "pad thai" pronounced the same as any other "pad"; that is, with /æ/.

Comment: I think the vowel charts you recently mentioned explain why this is so tough. See my CW answer below.

Comment: The word *pad* in *pad thai* is pronounced with the same vowel as *bath* in RP. (I'm Thai, by the way.) +1 for mentioning my favorite dish.

Comment: @tchrist I grew up in NYC and NJ and always heard (there), and still make, three distinct vowel sounds: *pawed, mawed, clawed, Claude* / *pod, mod, clod* / and *pad, mad, clad*. And I distinguish *fairy, furry,* and *ferry* too. :)

Comment: @DjinTonic No, that doesn't count. Your *pad / mad / clad* set does not have the /ɑ/ of FATHER but the /æ/ of TRAP as in *sass, Lassie, cat, ham*. That's why I mentioned the foreign word *pad* as in *Pad Thai* which **does** have the FATHER vowel not the TRAP vowel every time I've heard it.  Our Thai fellow Damkerng confirmed that's what he heard also almost a decade ago now.

Answer (score 8):

Do these work?

Sawed, sod and Sade. (Sade being the last name of Marquis de Sade.)

Bought, bot and Baht. (Baht being the currency of Thailand.)

Comment: Those triples don’t work for me because my *sawed* is rounded /sɔd/ but my *sod* 
and *Sade* are both unrounded /sɑd/.  Likewise my *bought* is rounded
/bɔt/ but my *bot* and *Baht* are both unrounded /bɑt/.

Answer (score 7):

I believe I’ve just discovered something that sheds light on this mystery. Peter Shore kindly pointed out [this vowel chart](http://www.helsinki.fi/speechsciences/projects/vowelcharts/), in which figure the following two charts (amongst others).

First, the American one:

[image: American vowel chart]

And now the British one:

[image: British vowel chart]

This probably explains why it’s so hard for me to find a minimal triple, since General American has only two vowels there, not three.  So the reason I could not find a minimal triple is because ***there cannot be one*** in General American.  We just don’t have that phoneme.

---

<sub>Making this answer **Community Wiki** so that I don’t gain reps from answering my own question.</sub>

Comment: Just to make it clearer, can you say what 'there' is? (which items labeled in the two diagrams are you referring to? and which corresponding lexical sets? hot/pot, caught, .. which are which two?

Comment: @Mitch Sure. I was looking for a minimal triple amongst /ɑ, ɒ, ɔ/.  But it looks like GA doesn’t even have all three of those.

Comment: That link to Uni of Helsinki website got rotten during website redesign - maybe you can find it again? This is **VERY** interesting comparison of vowels, explains a lot.

Comment: The American vowel chart is a little wonky; in AmE, *pot* has the /ɑ/ vowel, and not the /ɔ/ vowel.

Answer (score 5):

I'm betting you can find this in a Scottish or Irish English accent. I'm no expert, but I would suggest looking at cat/caught/cot as a possible triple of those vowels. You'd have to find one that escaped the caught/cot merger, and that has a rather back variant of the BATH vowel. To wit:

> cat /kɑt/
>   caught /kɒt/
>   cot /kɔt/

In addition, most Scottish and Irish English dialects are rhotic.

Comment: I thought everyone had *cat* as `/kæt/`?  It’s hard to find a for-sure `/ɑ/`; for example, I think most people fuse either *baa-ed* with *bod*, or else fuse *bod* with *bawd*; I don’t know if anyone has all three.  I’ve played around with imported words like like *khan, bhaat, phaal*, trying to get something that won’t merge without requiring a nonrhotic accent to get there. I know only some Scots accents, and not enough Irish ones, myself. I know there are a lot more than any I have ever heard, from that page I linked to.

Comment: That page is what made me think of it ... some of the Scottish dialects, e.g. Hawick, don't seem to have an /æ/ at all.

Comment: Well, that’s interesting!

Comment: My East Alabama dialect distinguishes the ɑ-set from the ɒ-set in my triples above mostly by length, but there's a definite front glide at the end of the latter. And the 'mid-Atlantic' dialect I was formally taught as an actor distinguishes all three on dictionary lines - artificial, perhaps, but wholly appropriated by long use.

Comment: Mine is a fairly mild Scottish accent, with more than a hint of RP, and to me cat, caught and cot sound entirely distinct, as do khan, con and corn and pawed, pod and pad.

Comment: @RoryAlsopThanks very much, that’s just the confirmation of direct experience that I was looking for! I would never have thought of using *cat* for that.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the following triple, which however is only valid for non rhotic accents :

```
bard /bɑːd/
bod /bɒd/
baud /bɔːd/
```

Comment: I had already thought of non-rhotic *cart / cot / caught* but that didn’t help me because I’m rhotic.  I can’t believe how much trouble I have hearing `ɒ` vs `ɔ`; I have to think about it really, really hard to generate or perceive a distinction between those.  Certainly rounding-vs-nonrounding is phonemic for me, but the degree of rounding may not be.

Comment: @tchrist: I believe /ɒ/ and /ɔ/ are allophonic in General American, which may be why you're having trouble hearing the difference; they certainly seem to be for me. My /ɔ/ covers a fairly wide range, depending on the following vowel; close to /ɒ/ for *claw,* and close to /o/ for *cloth*, so *awful* and *often* (or *offal*, a word I almost never use) have a significant difference in their vowels, since the first has the vowel of *awe* and the second of *off*. So I generate the two vowels without even having to think about it, but I find it hard to hear the difference.

Comment: @PeterShor I bet that’s it.  BTW, my *awful, often, off, and awe* all have a fairly “long” `/ɔː/`, and are completely identical in their starts for me.  And *awl* and *all* are homophones with the same vowel as the other four; they sound nothing like the *a* in German *alle* or Spanish *María*, the way they seem to for many SoCal speakers, who’ve lost all rounding.

Comment: And of course, I meant following *consonant* above, if you haven't already figured it out. My *claw* and my *cloth* would probably count as two different vowels if my *clause* wasn't halfway in between them.

Answer (score 2):

It's awkward that this is required to work in a rhotic accent, because that unfortunately removes most /a:/ syllables and a good deal of /ɔ:/ syllables, too. Perhaps you'd allow:

- lakhs, locks, lawks!
- mahl, moll, maul

If a portion of a word is allowed to accompany two whole words:

- khak(i), cock, caulk
- cast, cost, caust(ic)

With the help of a name or two:

- [Tatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatars), totter, tauter
- Kali, collie, [Cawley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cawley)
- Dali, dolly, [Dawley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawley)
- Mali, molly, [Mawley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawley_Hall)
- [Pali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali), poly, Paulie

Answer (score 1):

Paul, poll, pa'll (father will)

This works in my accent, I round Paul, but not pa or spa

I also don't merge poll and pole, since poll doesn't have a diphthong for me so it's a quadruplet

Answer (score 1):

## Minimal triple: *Bach’s, box, balks*

On [his website](https://www.aschmann.net/AmEng/#CotCaughtMerger), Rick Aschmann provides the answer of *Bach’s / box / balks* as a ***minimal triple*** for /ɑ, ɒ, ɔ/, which applies only to those speakers with **neither** the *father–bother* merger **nor** the *cot–caught* merger. I don’t personally have this one because I have *father–bother*.

To my personal surprise, I’ve also realized since I wrote this question that I don’t myself possess the *cloth–caught* merger of [ɒ, ɔ] into just one of those two, even though I don’t normally think of /ɒ/ being phonemically distinct from /ɔ/. Because I have the *father–bother* merger but **not** the *cot–caught* merger, for the longest time I hadn’t noticed that I do **not** have the *cloth–caught* merger either.