# Psychology of diphthongs

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics, diphthongs, phonemes

First of all, technically this probably should be at the [English Language Learners site](https://ell.stackexchange.com), because I'm an English learner, but my intuition says I'll probably get more useful answers here because of my question's nature. Tell me if I'm wrong about it.

Now, I'll try to tell briefly my experience learning about diphthongs. 
Recently, I talked (text messages) with a 15 y/o General American speaker about English pronunciation. The main topic was diphthongs. I wanted to know more about their nature, how native speakers understand it. And what really surprised me is he didn't really know what vowels I was talking about. From all vowels he only named 2 which as he considered consist from 2 "parts" — /ɔɪ/ and /aʊ/. Also, /ɔɪ/, as he said, consists from /oʊ/ + /iː/ while /aʊ/ consists from some vowel + some glide (he didn't tell about /u:/. Also, the starting "some vowel" first appeared to him to exist in English as standalone which surprised me, but then he couldn't name a word with this "vowel"). Then he said /oʊ/, /aɪ/, /eɪ/ diphthongs appear to be single-vowel sounds to him. After some conversation, he kinda agreed that /aɪ/ has two points. When listened to /oʊ/ pronunciation on dictionary.com he heard it as a single-vowel sound, although for me (a Russian speaker), it had some glide to /u:/. Then I asked him to pronounce /oʊ/ and then /u:/ and *then* he realized it's still an /oʊ/. So, /u:/ sounds like an optional addition to the first sound. He nevertheless couldn't name the reason behind the move to /u:/. The same situation with /eɪ/ sometimes having /i:/ after first sound.

At the end of our talk I had got quite a lot of information about how he pronounces vowels, but almost none information about *why* he pronounces them  this way. For example why can't he move to /u:/ after first sound in /aɪ/ and move to /i:/ after first sound in /aʊ/. Why he moves to /i:/ in /eɪ/ but doesn't in /e/ etc.

So basically, I want to find some deep information about psychology of English pronunciation, or at least some ideas on this topic. I found nothing on the internet yet.

Comment: Since he was native, his English is completely subconscious, and he didn't learn it the same way as non-natives learn.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the psychology of English pronunciation'? they're just noises passed down from other languages like Latin, French and German. Presumably from when the first caveman said 'ugg'...

Comment: Most native English speakers haven't got a clue what a diphthong is or which vowels are diphthongs, let alone how they came to be so.

Comment: In Russian, all vowel sounds are single vowels. So maybe because of it it appears weird when you're told that some vowels need some "addition" to them. This appears very unusual and needing some explanation...

Comment: Most English speakers have very little understanding or insight into how their language works at any level - phonetics, phonology, morphology, syntax, pragmatics, whatever. (I suspect the same is true for speakers of other languages, but I don't know for sure). What you're calling "psychology" is I think simply "understanding" or "knowledge" - there's no psychology involved.

Comment: I don't agree. If you do something but don't know how you do it - there's clearly some psychology here.

Comment: @ValentinDrozdov There's a lot of psychology there. How do you keep your balance on a bicycle? You clearly _can_ do it, but it's very difficult to explain to someone exactly how it is done. There are so many things we do but we don't know how we do it, much more than those things we can explain how to do it.

Comment: @ColinFine I don't think Freud would have agreed.

Comment: You are Russian, right? Have you ever heard of [terminal devoicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final-obstruent_devoicing#Russian)? If yes, when did you first do? Do your fellow native speakers know it? — German features terminal devoicing as well but few speakers are actually aware of it, let alone know the name for it. Germans also never start a word with a vowel, but a [glottal stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop) without being aware of it. Those are two of the key features of a German accent in other languages – just like diphthongs are a key feature of an English accent.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft actually, we almost certainly had this in school. Terminal devoicing is known here. But when I started adding a word (starting with a voiced consonant) after it so it wouldn't be isolated, I firstly was surprised as devoicing seemed to disappear 100%. But then I realized we actually can do devoicing even in this case, but it kinda adds some discomfort pronouncing it. So it depends on laziness.

Comment: This question is really bizarre for anyone who has taught English: English vowel combinations such as ou in out or lout are learned as vowel combinations. Not as diphhongs. See this charming book to see how native speakers interiorize pronunciation: https://books.google.com/books/about/English_Pronunciation_Illustrated.html?id=o0ke57u9RLUC (yes, BrE but the principle applies to all English). It shows how the phoneme combinations work (or don't) because English contains many exceptions....to the rules.

Comment: This made me wonder how much language theory English schools teach. We (Czech Republic) were taught about morphemes, phonemes, vowels, consonants, and diphthongs at high school, and some of it also at elementary school.

Comment: *Recently, I talked (text messages) with a 15 y/o General American speaker about English pronunciation. The main topic was diphthongs.* This was your mistake: A 15-year-old would know little of diphthongs.

Answer (score 35):

#### TL;DR

All tense monophthongs in English become non-phonemic, phonetic-only diphthongs with weak off-glides in most speakers and contexts. Minor phonologic effects like this are part of getting an accent right, but they do not change the abstract phoneme, which is still just /e/ or /o/, /i/ or /u/.

Native speakers do not think of those phonologic effects as producing diphthongs because they are not phonemic diphthongs, merely phonetic ones which don’t count. Untrained natives speakers always think about their language’s sounds only in simple phonemes, not in complicated phonetics.

That’s the only psychological phenomenon at work here.

See also [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/374420/2085) and [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/375487/2085).

---

---

---

## Language Interference

Like Spanish, [Russian has a five-vowel system of monophthongs, where any diphthongs are always written out explicitly right there in the spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology#Diphthongs). What’s confusing you is that English doesn’t work that way: its writing often fails to reflect whether a tense monophthong relaxes into a diphthong for a variety of reasons. The most important one is that our spelling reflects the phonemics of Middle English not the phonetics of Modern English. Other reasons in part include because of how this is automatic due to our loose articulation, and in part because its effect varies between speakers. Spelling never represents phonetics anyway, just phonemics at best.

Your mother tongue’s phonetics are confusing you because the phonetic rules in Russian work differently than the phonetic rules in English work. Phonemics are easy, but phonetics can be hard. You have to pay attention to abstract phonemics in order to think about a language’s sounds the way a native speaker does. But until you follow the same subtle phonetic rules for how to realize those phonemes, you’ll always sound foreign, and you may be confused or confusing.

In English as with any language, native speakers have trained our minds to “hear” only **phonemic** differences and ignore **phonetic** ones. You haven’t done that yet. The reason we don’t “hear” the word *no* in English as having a diphthong is because it is only a phonetic effect, not a phonemic one, and it’s phonemes that make one word different from another.

Phonemically it’s still just /no/, not /now/ or /noʷ/ or /noʊ̯/ or /nəɵ̯/ or
whatnot, because **those are not phonemes** in English. There is no such thing as a minimal pair in English between /no/ and /now/, so those last ones
should be in phonetic brackets **not** phonemic slashes, since diphthongal **/ow/ is *not* a phoneme in English**.

While there are many languages where these pairs with and without the trailing glide do contrast phonemically, English is not one such.

Phonemic /o/ in English becomes
phonetic [oʷ], [ɐʉ̯], [ɒʊ̯], [əɵ̯], [ɛʊ̯], [œː], [œɤ̯̈], [œʉ̯], [œʊ̯],
[oə̯], [oʊ̯], [ɔʊ̯], [ɵʊ̯], or [ʌʊ̯] in this or that region or speaker. But
it can **also** remain a purely monophthongal [o] or [oː] in some speakers
and utterances.  You have to hear all those differing phonetics as the
simple /o/ phoneme, and right now you are not doing that.

That’s like how English has no minimal pair contrasting /e/ and /ej/, which means that diphthongal **/ej/ is *not* an English phoneme**. Sure [ej] happens, but it is not a phoneme. It’s true that phonemic /e/ is usually realized as a phonetic diphthong in English,
whether that’s as [æɪ̯], [äɪ̯], [ei], [eɪ̯], [ej], [eʲ], [ɛɪ̯], or even
bizarrely enough [ʌɪ̯]. But it can also remain a phonetic monophthong [e]
or [eː].  No matter the sounds, all those are still just the same phoneme, /e/.

The problem for speakers who come from a language that lacks these implicit, automatic phonological changes that English makes to all its tense vowels is that you guys will hear different phonetics and think you’re hearing different phonemes when you aren’t.  Or at least, when we aren’t, which is the problem.

### Putting the shoe on the other foot

This difficulty works both ways. It’s also hard for English speakers learning languages where an unconscious phonetic side-effect becomes a different phoneme
altogether if they do that English-only thing in the language they’re trying to learn.

That’s where “foreign accents” come from: you’re unconsciously mis-applying the “foreign” language’s phonologic rules for phonetic variants to some other language that isn’t supposed to follow the first one’s phonetic rules. So it sounds off; often recognizable, but off.

People coming from English who are learning Romance languages like Spanish have to be explicitly taught to hold their mouths tighter so that they **don’t** add glides to all the Romance vowels like we do with English vowels.  Even lookalike words like *no* are pronounced differently in the two languages. So the common Spanish word *no* is actually pronounced [no] in Spanish, not [noʷ] with a terminal off-glide as in English, because they don’t speak with as relaxed an articulation as we do. They keep their close (“tense”) vowels close throughout their articulation, but we do not. We always change ours a little at the end.

The Latin words *lex* meaning “law” and *rex* meaning “king” evolved into diphthongized *ley* and *rey* in Spanish; these are basic words you normally hear all the time. Even more confusingly than it does with the simple word *no*,
this unconscious mutation of tense vowels by English speakers first learning Spanish can turn accidentally turn what should be minimal pairs like *re–rey* and *le-ley* in Spanish into confusable soundalikes because of the “foreign accent” intruding.

An untrained English speaker is simply unable to correctly pronounce simple little Spanish words like *le* and *re* without those sounding like a Spanish speaker would pronounce *le**y*** and *re**y***, which are two entirely different words. Because we automatically turn close/tense vowels into diphthongs, English speakers will naturally (mis-)pronounce something like Spanish *le* as [leʲ], thereby making it sound closer to the pronunciation of the word *ley* in Spanish, which is just plain [lej] “just like it’s spelled”. Context would almost always be enough to help the native Spanish speaker differentiate which of the two words the English speaker had intended to say but didn’t quite do so.

However, there are certainly cases where legitimate confusion **can**
arise, like between the minimal pair *estés–estéis*. Those are close not
only in sound but also in meaning.  Both words are the present subjunctive
for a particular *to be* verb that’s been conjugated into the second
person, but the first is in the second-person singular and the second is in
the second-person plural.  Singular *estés* is pronounced /esˈtes/
phonemically and [e̞s̺ˈt̪e̞s̺] phonetically, while plural *esté**i**s* is
/esˈtejs/ phonemically and [e̞s̺ˈt̪e̞js̺] phonetically, so it’s nothing
more than that /ej/ diphthong in *estéis* which marks that one as being in
the plural.  This is possible because unlike English, Spanish **does** have
an actual /ej/ phonemic diphthong that can participate in minimal pairs
like this. Our lack of the same is what makes these two words “confusables” for
English speakers.

Singular versus plural is an important distinction to make and to hear
made, but here it’s not one that an untrained English speaker learning
Spanish can even reproduce: English cannot even distinguish those two
words’ differentiating sounds! So because the English phoneme in
English *place* /ples/ [pʰleʲs] generally comes out with phonetics
that fall **between** the two Spanish phonemes of monophthong /e/ and
diphthong /ej/, it’s really hard for an English speaker to hear or
reproduce the Spanish ones accurately. It takes a long time. It will
likely take you a long time smoothing out your Russian phonetics
English, too, and for many of the same reasons.

Differences in one language are not differences in others. In English, /d/ and /ð/ are contrasting phonemes, but in Spanish they are exactly the same phoneme but which one you say is controlled by the phonologic environment, just like whether we say our /e/ as [e] or [eʲ] in English also varies phonetically. That’s because in all Iberian Romance languages, voiced stops like [d] automatically become fricative allophones like [ð] between vowels.

It’s just “what one does” in these languages, something that happens automatically once you get the accent down: you turn intervocalic voiced stops into fricatives (and often even approximants).  If you don’t do that, it sounds terrible to a native speaker. You have “a bad accent” or “a foreign accent”. Sure, you’re getting the phonemes right but the phonetics are all wrong. The same thing happens at first when people from certain language groups try to learn English. They’re hearing the wrong things, and not hearing the right ones.

## Phonemic diphthongs versus phonetic ones

In English, we turn **all** our tense vowels in phonetic diphthongs with slight off-glides. We don’t think of those as diphthongs, though. They’re just automatic phonetic after-effects, not part of our ideal abstract phonemes we use in our heads to tell one word from another.

English has just three ***phonemic* diphthongs**: /ɔɪ̯/ as in *boy*, /aɪ̯/
as in *buy*, and /aʊ̯/ as in *cow*.  (For the sake of convenience,
sometimes those are respectively written /oj/, /aj/, and /aw/, but that’s
just an alternate notation for the same three basic phonemes.)

The rest of what you’re talking about is a regular modification of **all** tense vowels. These phonetic diphthongs caused by off-glides don't really count as phonemic diphthongs. They're the result of how tight/loose or tense/lax that English articulation is (as compared with say, Italian), where a tense vowel in isolation “always” gains a trailing glide, either [w] or [j] (sometimes written [u̯] and [ɪ̯]) depending on which tense vowel we’re talking about.  It’s a way of relaxing the tenseness.

That means not just /e/ and /o/ as in *they* and *show*, but even /i/ and /u/ in *see* [siːʲ] and *who* [huːʷ] get little off-glides phonetically. It can even happen with /ɑ/, as we see in the [eye-dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect) re-spellings of *paw* [pɔːʷ] for *pa*, *grampaw* for *grandpa*, and *meemaw* for *mama* or *grandma*. When writers use eye-dialect spellings like that, they’re trying to tell you that those words end like the word *law* [lɔː] not like the word *la* [lɑ] in those speakers’ versions (and that those are different sounds as far as the writer is concerned).

Nobody thinks about the **phonetic** side-effects of how our **phonology** works. It’s part of getting the accent “right” when you’re learning the language. You won’t find it in our books, nor even in our dictionaries for the most part, since native speakers don’t need to be taught to do these things.

Although some speakers do have more of pure monophthong for [e] and [o] when there’s a consonant following that tight vowel, especially when that consonant is [ɹ], everybody adds a glide at the end to relax it if the tense vowel occurs at the end of the word.

## Tense /e/ and /o/ in General American

These next sets below all have a tense /e/ for their stressed vowel in General American, the vowel that children (but not linguists) are taught to call “a long a”. A native speaker will hear the first word of each series below also occurring “in full” at the start of each subsequent word in that row. Notice how the off-glide after the tense vowel, variously written [ej] or [eɪ̯] or [eʲ], is not included in how we think of these phonemically.

***This*** is why your fifteen-year-old didn’t think of [oʷ] and [eʲ] as diphthongs, just as the basic phonemes /o/ and /e/. We don’t think about phonetics, just about phonemics, and there is no diphthong in the phoneme: phonemically they’re monophthongs even though in practice they usually are phonetic diphthongs.

#### Notice how simple the phonemic notation below is; *this* is how native speakers think of these words.

- bay, bake, bear, berry /be, bek, ber, ˈberi/
- day, date, dare, dairy /de, det, der, ˈderi/
- fey, fake, fair, fairy /fe, fek, fer, ˈferi/
- gay, gate, Gary /ge, get, ˈgeri/
- hey, hate, hair, hairy /he, het, her, ˈheri/
- Kay, Kate, Kerry /ke, ket, ˈkeri/
- may, mate, mare, Mary /me, met, mer, ˈmeri/
- pay, pate, pear, parry /pe, pet, per, ˈperi/
- pray, prate, prayer, prairie /pre, pret, prer, ˈpreri/
  <sub>(NB: that’s monosyllabic *prayer* /prer/ as in saying one’s prayers; when *prayer* means one who prays, it has two syllables /ˈpre.jər/)</sub>
- ray, rate, rare /re, ret, rer/
- they, they’d, their /ðe, ðed, ðer/
- way, wait, wear, wary /we, wet, wer, ˈweri/

---

These next sets all have a tense /o/ for their stressed vowel in General American, the vowel that children (but not linguists!) are taught to call “a long o”. Notice how the off-glide after the tense vowel, so [ow] or [oʊ̯] or [oʷ], is not included in how we think of these phonemically.

- bow, boat, boar /bo, bot, bor/
- dough, dote, Dory /do, dot, ˈdori/
- foe, phone, for /fo, fon, for/
- go, goat, gore, gory /go, got, gor, ˈgori/
- glow, gloat, glory /glo, glot, ˈglori/
- hoe, hope, whore, hoary /ho, hop, h⁽ʷ⁾or, ˈhori/
- low, lope, lore, lorry /lo, lop, lor, ˈlori/
- mow, moat, more, Morey /mo, mot, mor, ˈmori/
- no, nope, nor, nori /no, nop, nor, ˈnori/
- Poe, poke, pore /po, pok, por/
- row, wrote, Rory /ro, rot, ˈrori/
- so, soap, sore, sorry /so, sop, sor, ˈsori/
- stow, stoke, store, story /sto, stok, stor, ˈstori/
- toe, taupe, tore, Tory /to, top, tor, tori/
- woe, woke, wore /wo, wok, wor/

Like all tense vowels in English, both /e/ and /o/ always have a slight off-glide at the end of an open syllable, meaning the versions in the first word in each row that don’t have a consonant at their end. That tiny little off-glide is considerably less noticeable when the syllable doesn’t immediately end there like in the rest of the words on the same row, and in many speakers it can even become a pure monophthong in those positions.  But never in the first.

This phonetic monophthongization happens in the [Inland North](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English) dialect as spoken in the Upper Midwest of the Great Lakes region, especially in areas affected by the [Northern Cities Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Cities_Vowel_Shift) (which is a new kind of chain-shift like the infamous Great Vowel Shift of old). But it also occurs in many Californian speakers as well as in speakers of some dialects at further remove from North America, such as in Scotland.

Additionally, the normally phonemic tense–lax distinction between /e/ with /ɛ/ and sometimes also /o/ with /ɔ/ can be neutralized in phonologic environments where those phonemes are followed by a nasal /n, m, ŋ/ or by a rhotic /r/. Once you have neutralization, then even when these do still vary in this or that speaker, these now become only phonetic allophones of the same merged phoneme in the minds of the listener.

## Summary

Native speakers have trained themselves to notice only those differences in sounds that change which word is actually being said. They do not notice differences that make no difference, including variances under neutralization and those resulting from different amounts of off-glide rounding via [ʷ] or off-glide palatalization via [ʲ]. Those are minor effects that never change the word.

Comment: You explained phonetic diphthongs more or less enough, and I know ee and oo sounds has some glide too. Still there's a thing, that boy said - ee and oo have kinda two "beats" as he called them, while /oʊ/ and /eɪ/ - only one. Maybe you understand it? --- Also, still there're questions about /ɔɪ/, /aʊ/, /aɪ/ - phonemic diphthongs. Shortly, why the starting sounds of /aʊ/, /aɪ/ don't exist in English as standalone if these diphthongs, as you said, are phonemic? If you hear them as diphthongs, why you don't (even can't) use their parts independently?

Comment: @ValentinDrozdov You mean like how *f**a**ther* has the same standalone vowel in its first syllable as the one that forms the pre-glide syllabic nucleus of the diphthongs  /aʊ/ and /aɪ/? Just remember that English “can’t” have a close/tight vowel at the end of a syllable without a slight off-glide to it and you’ll do  just fine; that off-glide that happens automatically there is not phonemic because we cannot say that sound there without it, and even if we did manage to, nobody would hear it as a different word.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your comment, but as I know "father" don't have exact vowel as start sounds in /aʊ/ and /aɪ/. I'm not sure I understand what you say next - words "file" and "feel" both have ee at the end of syllable, but in first case the glide is big and in the second case small if exists, as I understand. What I don't understand is why you "can't" pronounce the first part of  /aʊ/ or /aɪ/ and **not to** make glide to oo/ee.
I've read your updated post, it has quite a lot of useful information, but it seems this particular point is omitted there :)

Comment: @ValentinDrozdov Since for me, *father* /ˈfaðər/ does indeed have the very same stressed vowel as a monophthong as we find in the syllabic nuclei of two of our three phonemic diphthongs, the /aw/ of *cow* /kaw/ and the /aj/ of *guy* /gaj/, I really don’t know what you mean when you claim that “we can’t say it”. What we cannot do is have a tense vowel end a word without an off-glide to finish that word. Hence *they* and *sew* have glides at the end. We cannot say those as monophthongs in isolation without the glide,  although many of us can do so with a following consonant as in *make, spoke*.

Comment: @ValentinDrozdov English must be spoken with a lax/relaxed/loose articulation, not with a tense/tight/firm articulation. Because of this, all tense vowels naturally loosen up immediately upon being said. We relax them. You’re hearing this natural relaxation as a diphthong, and we are not hearing it that way. It’s simply something that always happens because English properly spoken is not a tensely articulated language, but rather a laxly articulated one. So all tense vowels always change a little. It’s like how Russian has both hard and soft variants of its consonants.

Comment: It is very interesting to hear that this is the same vowel as in those diphthongs, but I doubt this is true for most of speakers. For example, look at [this RP chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation#/media/File:RP_English_diphthongs_chart.svg) — the diphthongs there have different starting sounds, and unlikely equal to one of [RP monothongs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation#/media/File:Modern_General_British_monophthong_chart.svg).

Comment: @ValentinDrozdov I'm not talking about RP. I'm talking about GA, the English variant which I'm a native speaker of. You'd have to ask an RP speaker about RP, but you asked a GA speaker, your fifteen-year-old, so I as a GA speaker am explaining to you why he said what he did. For GA, please see [the Kenyon and Knott](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGEnd.png) charts in the two answers I linked to.

Comment: I didn't link GA chart, because diphthongs' start points are shown there as one point, but that 15 year boy I talked with did say they have different start points and he lives in USA (and he said his accent is GA IIRC)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65382/discussion-between-valentin-drozdov-and-tchrist).

Comment: Your contention that there is no phonemic contrast between /no/ and /now/ is at odds with the account in SPE, which notes the contrast between "motto" (with unstressed final and flapped /t/) and "Plato" (with low stressed final and unflapped /t/).

Comment: @GregLee Are you saying that the vowels after the /t/ in those two words are **phonemically** distinct from one another? If so, what’s a minimal pair that proves this? I'm guessing you're saying that *motto* has a flat  /o/ without an off-glide at the end and that *Plato* has /ow/ with an off-glide at the end. Phonetically you may be right, but I'd really like to see a minimal pair where nothing whatsoever changes but the putative pair of contrasting phonemes. Otherwise I'll be stuck thinking that what you identify here is only a phonologic effect, not a phonemic one. :)

Comment: In the SPE analysis, "motto" ends in lax /o/ and "Plato" ends in tense /ɔ:/.  Those are phonologically distinct.  (SPE does not have phonemes.)  Phonetically, both end in glide [w] preceded by tense [o:] with 3 or 0 stress.  I don't know what you count as a "phonologic effect", but I would have guessed this counts as one.

Comment: Wait... people say *motto* without an off-glide? Who?

Comment: I was aware of the phonetic/phonemic distinction in a vague sense before reading this, but this is such an excellent write-up and it clarifies a lot! As someone from New York now living elsewhere, I find that people often don’t pronounce my name correctly. It’s because for them "pay, pear, parry" are phonemically the same, while in my dialect these three _are_ distinct phonemes, and only the last one matches how my name is pronounced. Up here in Boston, most people use one of the first two sounds instead, seemingly at random, because for them it’s all one sound.

Comment: "sorry" might not be a good example for the /o/ phoneme, since for me and many other AE speakers it's more like /'sari/.  (Or /'sɔri/? I don't think I have a distinct /ɔ/, and in any case don't understand the difference between /a/ and /ɔ/.)

Comment: "_Untrained natives speakers **always think about their language’s sounds only in simple phonemes**_" – I'm sure most of us don't even do that!

Comment: @aschepler From what you describe,maybe you have not only the *cot–caught* /ɒ~ɔ/ merger but also the *father–bother* /a~ɑ~ɔ/ merger in a way that’s left you with just a single unrounded /ɑ/ as your only remaining stressed vowel phoneme in all four of those words. I have only the second merger but not the first, so for me a /'sɑri/ is a colorful lady’s garment from India. The thing is that the tense–lax opposition is neutralized before /r/, so /o/ vs. /ɔ/ disappears there. I say *sorry* just like I say the word *sore* or *soar* with an extra /i/ tacked on, so /'sori/ ～ /'sɔri/, never /'sɑri/.

Comment: Brilliant answer for sure. This made me realize why English people always sound so funny when trying to pronounce foreign words (no offence) and why don't they "pronounce it like it's written". It simply sounds the same to them, phonemically.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, for me "sorry" and "sari" are exact homophones.  I do think I pronounce a slight difference between the first vowels of "father" and "bother" or "Khan" and "con", but I would have trouble hearing the difference.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/599686/2085).

Answer (score 8):

From the point of view of most native English speakers, diphthongs such as /eɪ/, /aɪ/ etc are not noticeably different from other, monophthongal vowels.

[SIL](http://www.glossary.sil.org/term/diphthong) defines a diphthong as "A diphthong is a phonetic sequence, consisting of a vowel and a glide, that is **interpreted as a single vowel**."

The distinct individual sounds of a language are called phonemes.  Each diphthong is [regarded](http://www.tedpower.co.uk/folkchart.htm) as a phoneme, not as a combination of two phonemes.

You can see the same thing in traditional (non-IPA) transcription systems; for example, M-W [transcribe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lake) "lake" as \ˈlāk.

The way that native English speakers are taught /eɪ/ when learning to spell, it is a "[long A](https://www.spellzone.com/blog/Six_Ways_to_Spell_the_Long_A_Sound.htm)", not a combination of sounds.

Historically, most of the diphthongal phonemes go back to set of changes initiated at the time of the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift#Overall_changes).  In the 14th century, the "long A" actually *was* /a:/. Over the following centuries it shifted to /ɛː/ and /e:/ and then eventually /eɪ/.  (Of course, its quality can still vary depending on dialect and sociolect.)

Comment: Of course I'm not saying that person was a CIA agent and didn't want to tell me the secrets of English language. On the contrary, the fact that natives don't understand the reason for their pronunciation is **the** reason I asked this question, otherwise that person would tell me everything and I wouldn't be here...

Comment: I understand that diphthongs are interpreted as single vowels by natives, but the reason for that is what I don't understand.

Comment: Children learn sounds through imitation, not by a conscious process of "I'll start off with this sound then glide into that sound".  Why would they necessarily have a consciousness of something as two sounds, if it is merged together into one sound pronounced rapidly?  And then there's the fact that in the spelling system, when they come to learn it, many of these diphthongs are represented a lot of the time by a single letter, while some monophthongs are double letters (like "ee") - so the writing system gives people no clue as to the existence of diphthongs, nor do the pedagogical methods.

Comment: The three phonemic diphthongs are the only ones that "count": /ɔɪ/ and /aʊ/ and /aɪ/. Everything else is a non-phonemic phonetic effect that varies between between regions, speakers, and utterances. Some speakers have actual monophthongs /e/ and /o/ without a trailing glide unless the sound has no following consonant, and that's the way Americans are taught to think of these.

Comment: **rjpond**, of course children don't have to understand this process, that's why this is a question to not children who explore English. I tried to say this in my previous comments.
**tchrist**, that's an interesting point, but as I wrote in the post, that 15-year old boy didn't hear a diphthong in "no", when listened to this:http://www.dictionary.com/browse/no?s=t
Btw, what do you hear here?

Comment: @ValentinDrozdov Are you Russian? Do you hear and interpret ц and ч as single sounds?

Comment: @curiousdannii yes.

Comment: @Valentin Well hearing and interpreting an affricate as one sound is basically the same as hearing and interpreting a diphthong as one sound.

Comment: @curiousdannii if it is so, it's not obvious to me. I don't even know how to divide these sounds into parts.

Comment: @ValentinDrozdov You mean you don't recognize the [ts] in Ц?

Comment: @IllidanS4 there's [s] after you say Ц but it's impossible to pronounce it without [s], so we understand it as noise.